# 'pubsubhubbub' support for EE?

Tags: add-on, channel-entries, seo, rss

A little background, we have a theory that content scrappers are using our feeds to scape and post our site content and it might be negatively effecting or search results. This topic was mentioned by Google engineer Matt Cutts at PubCon 2011. A solution that was put forth was to use ["Fat Pings"](http://www.labnol.org/internet/fat-pings-for-content-scrapers/20400/). Basically, ping Google as soon as the content is published so their servers have a strong record of the source server. Hosted services like Blogger and Wordpress.com already do this using [pubsubhubbub](http://code.google.com/p/pubsubhubbub/).

So my question is: Does anyone know if there is an existing add-on or code for doing 'pings' when content is added to a channel or feed in Expression Engine?

I found a couple support threads on the Ellis Labs site, but not any real mentions of a solution.
http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/132321/
http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/229845/

***Aside:*** *Are the Ellis Labs support forums incredibly slow for anyone else or is it just me?*

Comment: The Ellis Labs support forums are now community driven and official support is now commercial in that you need to sign up to one of their support plans. A lot of regular EE users left those forums long ago when they became less than useful.

Answer (score 2):

I implemented pubsubhubbub using Superfeedr and it's working well for me.

...and yes, the Ellis Labs support forums are maddeningly slow for me, too. Support is now a profit center for them, so free support is worse than a cost center, it competes with their business model.

[edited to correct spelling of Superfeedr]

Comment: I assume you mean [Superfeedr](http://superfeedr.com)?

Comment: Also, does that simply use an RSS to handle the update? I assume if so there is a slight delay before Superfeedr picks up the update. I was sort of looking for an active ping to happen when we publish the channel entry.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you're looking for, but we have [Sitemap Pinger](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/sitemap-pinger) extension